Laughing-Gate cover up
Moshe Rabbeinu was told that he can’t go into the holy land due to the incident with the water. We have other people who got into major trouble for seemingly doing something pretty valid or small things. Miriam is another example. Yaakov Avinu calling Esav his Lord etc.
(Yes, there is a concept of Tzaddikim being held to a higher standard.)
Now let's go back to the incident where Sarah Immeinu laughs when being told that she was going to have a kid. That’s seem like a pretty big no-no to laugh at.
It seems like that’s a pretty serious thing to do; laughing at a divine statement. But she never got into trouble (Thank goodness, or else we all might not be here today!)
Did it ever occur to you, or maybe it is written down that what happened was a sort of nepotistic favor that unfolded where G_d looked away from what happened, because he really wanted Yitzchak Avinu to be born?
Was this entire ‘laughing-gate’ swept under the rug, because the one above needed things moving and the last thing he would want is to get Sarah Immeinu into trouble and mess it up for himself by delaying Yitzchak Avinu’s birth? (Yes, I know that G_d is not a human, to behave and act like a human but there are plenty of incidents, in the kabbalistic lexicons, where it does seem like he reacts like a human would have).
Was there some sort of ‘laughing-gate’ cover up?

I seem to recall that there was some punishment, either for laughing or denying it, possibly related to women being invalid witnesses?

No, she was a prophetess. The inner lesson is that she wasn't laughing because she thought it was impossible, but laughing at the bracha. She heard, in the way it was phrased (i.e. Avraham was told Sarah would have a child, rather than she being told she would, or he being told he would - she listened), that it wasn't a permanent bracha, and the baby would die (and she was forseeing the Akeda), so she was laughing "ha, you call that a bracha" i.e. she was being a good mother and lobbying for her son. The malach who reassured her in response was the same one who stopped the Akeda.

Please explain the use of 'nepotistic' in your question. Collins dictionary definition "Nepotism is the unfair use of power in order to get jobs or other benefits for your family or friends."

@AvrohomYitzchok I think he means favoritism.


It seems like that’s a pretty serious thing to do; laughing at a divine statement. But she never got into trouble

According to some commentators, Sarah was indeed punished for laughing.
According the Midrash (see Rashi on Gen. 25:1, and BT BM 87a), there were cynics that suspected that it was Abhimelekh who had impregnated Sarah. R. Shim'on Sofer suggests that Sarah suffering such claims was a punishment for her laughing (see Shir Ma'on, p. 18).
Another Midrash (Pirqe de-Rabi Eli'ezer 32) relates that Samael (Satan) tricked Sarah into believing that Yishaq had been killed by Abhraham at the Aqeda and thus precipitated her death. The Hatham Sofer (citing the Panaeah Raza) suggests this was a punishment for laughing (see Oroth Hatham Sofer, p. 105).

I'm going to write an extension to translate these transliterations into English.

@shmosel you do you bud ;)
